# New to programming class (python 3.4) Coin change issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing the coin change problem (Taking a specific US dollar amount, and converting it into how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that is.)

I'm hung up on converting the amount. I'll put in $0.50 and get no results, but inputting 50 gives me 2 quarters.  Where am I going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#Display information about program
print("Change Calculator")
print()

#Input Data
choice = "y"
while choice.lower() == "y":
    dollarAmount = float(input("Enter dollar amount (for example, .56, 7.85): $"))
    if dollarAmount <= 0:
        print("Danger Will Robinson, Danger! Only positive numbers work! Try again")
        print()
    else:    
        print() #Displays correct amount of change
        print(dollarAmount//25, "Quarters: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%25
        print(dollarAmount//10, "Dimes: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%10
        print(dollarAmount//5, "Nickels: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%5
        print(dollarAmount//1, "Pennies: ")
        print()
        if dollarAmount >= 0:
            choice = input("Would you like to enter another amount? (y/n): ")
            print()

print("Goodbye!! May the force be with you.")
```

Comment: Are you getting an actual error or is it failing with no feedback?

Comment: Inside the else statement multiply dollarAmount by 100. The rest of the code assumes it's dealing with amounts in cents.

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. How would you prove the code does what it is intended to do?

Comment: @BSMP no, I'm getting feedback. The program works. It just doesn't recognize dollars, only cents. For instance, $7.37 only comes out as a nickel and two pennies.

Comment: @DanNagle Where inside the else statement?

Comment: `dollarAmount` comes into play in the second print() function so you can choose to do the multiplication either before or after the first print() function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dollarAmount` as if it were the number of cents, which is why it works when you enter the amount in cents.  If you want to enter the amount in dollars, you need to convert it to cents before performing your change computation.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this so I can see what you mean?

Comment: The example you gave (entering 50 works when you mean $0.50) is a perfectly good example.

Answer (score 0):

`dollarAmount` needs to be treated as an amount in cents. As I explained in my comment, you can do this by multiplying the amount by 100. See code below for where I would make the change.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#Display information about program
print("Change Calculator")
print()

#Input Data
choice = "y"
while choice.lower() == "y":
    dollarAmount = float(input("Enter dollar amount (for example, .56, 7.85): $"))
    if dollarAmount <= 0:
        print("Danger Will Robinson, Danger! Only positive numbers work! Try again")
        print()
    else:
        #Convert to cents 0.56 -> 56
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount * 100
        print() #Displays correct amount of change
        print(dollarAmount//25, "Quarters: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%25
        print(dollarAmount//10, "Dimes: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%10
        print(dollarAmount//5, "Nickels: ")
        dollarAmount = dollarAmount%5
        print(dollarAmount//1, "Pennies: ")
        print()
        if dollarAmount >= 0:
            choice = input("Would you like to enter another amount? (y/n): ")
            print()

print("Goodbye!! May the force be with you.")
```

Comment: Seriously...I feel like an idiot, but I really appreciate the help as my assignment is due tomorrow!